# setup python autocomplete in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm for python programming, now i want to switch to VS code but the intelisens and autocomplete of PyCharm seems better than VS code.

any one know how can i have the same features of PyCharm in vscode(the  autocomplete, function details and all).

i tried few extensions in vs code for python but still not same as PyCharm.

Comment: Why would you want to switch from Pycharm to VSCode? Pycharm is specific and well created mature product for Python while VSCode is a "swiss knife" for everything and will never cover all the benefits you get from dedicated tool. Sometimes it might have some bonus feature that does not exist in Pycharm, like ARepl to do live show for students or in speeches - You can have both on your pc and use whichever fits your task.

Comment: The python extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) + a selected interpreter (bottom right) should provide such features in .py files and notebooks. 
Additionally you can lint your files with Ruff (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charliermarsh.ruff)

Comment: @Drako We try to prevent discussions like "Which editor / IDE / tool / hardware … is better?" here on SO. The reason is simple: they distract from the actual question.

Comment: @KlausD. - original question was exactly about that - why don't have in one IDE functionality that exists in another and how to set up it in another. I did not brought additional IDEs in conversation and even did not say one is bad just pointed out that obviously you will never have same functionality in casual tool that you have in dedicated - that's just general truth. Also suggested having both on PC and using as needed. Could have mentioned that with existing extensions for VSCode I was not able to find anything close to Pycharm autocompletion - probably does not exist.

Comment: @Drako `probably does not exist`, if PyCharm can write code to do the autocompletion somebody can write a VSC extension that does the same

Comment: I'm leaning to think that this question is too broad. Unless there happens to be an extension out there that does exactly this, but I kind of doubt that. I'd suggest you ask multiple question posts, each about a highly specific feature that you want to "replicate"

Comment: @rioV8 - probably does not exist - means: at the moment of writing comment I am not aware of such tool. I never told that its not possible to write one in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Vscode needs to install extensions to complete more functions. For python, you need to install the [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension, which includes the [**Pylance**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) extension, which can bring intellisense and auto-completion.

If you are just getting started with vscode, [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) is a good start.

Here is more information on [vscode Intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) and [python Autocomplete and IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense) .

Comment: The question does not mention that author don't know how to get extension - problem is that extensions that you mention in your answer are providing worse experience of autocompletion than ones in a Pycharm - and its true - I have tested too. And its ok that Pycharm has better - check my comments to original question.